# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Installation Fail

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

TL;DR I might have screwed up my own computer and want to re-install Ubuntu from scratch

Yesterday, I bought a brand new PC and decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it, bought a SanDisk 8GB USB Flash Drive, burnt the .iso into the stick, boot from the USB, followed the install steps and it was ready to go. After around 3h i noticed the install status was just installing and removing things for 2h+n (things like gnome-user, etc). after doing some research the installation shouldn't take more than an hour for almost everyone. Powered down my PC and then reboot. I'm now presented with GNU GRUB screen with 3 options: Ubuntu, Advanced Ubuntu Boot, and System Setup.

'Ubuntu' boots with a timeout notice and around 4 [DEPEND] notices, and after this a 'Failed to start Load Kernel Module'. Afterwards it gives a normal Ubuntu loading screen and loops on forever (tested for 1.5h)

[image: pic related]

'Advanced' gives two options that are basically the same except for '(recovery mode)' both give around 6 options after the finish loading, such as dpkg or clean, none of them work and they print 'directory/module not found'

Finally, System Setup boots as normal and reboots the computer back to GRUB

I tried modifying the Boot order to reboot from the installation USB, isntead of 'ubuntu', to be greeted by the same installation screen from the start, installed at Minimal, and had patience this time, leaving it overnight. It started at 8:30PM, I woke up at 5AM, checked on it, and it was still going at it. 45min later it completes the installation, yet the same problems from before are still present.

As i mentioned before, the PC is new, so i don't have any important files (or any files at all) in the HDD, so if i could just obliterate anything contained within the Hard Drive and re-install clean with no interruption, it could probably solve my problem (hopefully).

It's also weird that my installation would've taken so much, it's a relatively decent PC (i guess it is: i5 @ 3.9GHz, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD)

Comment: It sounds like you're not dual-booting with Windows. I'd turn off Secure Boot in the BIOS. Then I'd boot the Ubuntu Live USB, start gparted, lay down a fresh GPT partition table on the HDD, quit gparted, and click on the "Install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop. Should only take 20 minutes.